# STM32 custom board debug

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, st-link

I am developing my own board for a basic UART communication to start with and I am unable to flash the microcontroller.
I am using STM32F405RT6 and the STLink V3 debugger to program it I have tried to power the microcontroller from the on-board 3.3V regulator as well as external 3.3V and neither of them made any difference.
Could you please tell me the first things to check on my design?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Can you at least get the chip ID via the ST Link and STM32CubeProgrammer?
Are you using the correct wires with the ST Link V3?
Are you powering on your board? 
The programmer doesn't give power.

Comment: Are the decoupling caps near the VDD inputs of the MCU? Did you measure the output voltage of the 3V3 Regulator? You may need pull ups to 3V3 on your SWDIO and SWCLK lines, which I am not sure are present in your schematic ( I am assuming you are using SWD to program it as there is a SWD connector).

Comment: I'd say "the first thing to check" is always whether or not you have the VCC voltage that you think you have. The second would be the wiring to STLink. And couple more things: VCAP1/2 capacitors seem to be too big, direct connection of PA9/10 to power rail is suspicious, VDDA not connected to VDD

Comment: @md-raz SWDIO and SWCLK have internal pull-ups activated on reset, specifically to ensure correct power up and support JTAG/SWO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't work without all the power supply pins being connected.

You have left VDDA unconnected, and VBAT too.

Comment: VDDA - absolutely. But datasheet does not explicitly require VBAT to be connected, unless internal reset is off (the mode that is not supported by this chip). I'd connect it anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that one. Vdda is essential because the clock system runs on that pin.